# Show that $f(x)=\int_{[a,x]} g \, dm$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $g$ be summable on $[a,b]$. Show that $f(x)=\int_{[a,x]} g \, dm$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. ($m$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$)

---

First let $g$ be a simple function. For simplicity assume that
$$
 g(t) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill y_1   \hfill & \text{ if $t\in[a,c)$} \\
      \hfill y_2 \hfill & \text{ if $t=c$} \\
\hfill y_3 \hfill & \text{ if $t\in (c,b]$} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Assume that $x\in [a,c)$. It is clear that $$\int_{[a,x]} g \, dm=y_1 m([a,x))=y_1(x-a)$$

which is a linear function so is continuous. We can prove other cases similarly using fact that measure of a single point is $0$.

Is this correct? Also how can I generalize this to summable functions (not simple ones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Try using the definition of continuity. You want to make the following inequality

$$\left|\int_{[x, x+t]} g \, dm\right| < \varepsilon$$

You know the integral is finite, so $g$ should be bounded on this compact interval. Thus you can take $|t| < \delta$ with $\delta$ small to make the value on the LHS to be less than $M \delta$, where $M$ is the bound.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{[a,x]} g=\int_{[a,b]}g\cdot \chi_{[a,x]},$$
where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. Apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude the statement for any sequence of $x_n \rightarrow x$. The result then follows.